# how to pass asterisk into ls command inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ls

Hi… Need a little help here…

I tried to emulate the DOS' `dir` command in Linux using bash script. Basically it's just a wrapped `ls` command with some parameters plus summary info. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# default to current folder 
if [ -z "$1" ]; then var=.;
  else var="$1"; fi

# check file existence
if [ -a "$var" ]; then
  # list contents with color, folder first
  CMD="ls -lgG $var --color --group-directories-first"; $CMD;

  # sum all files size
  size=$(ls -lgGp "$var" | grep -v / | awk '{ sum += $3 }; END { print sum }')
  if [ "$size" == "" ]; then size="0"; fi 

  # create summary
  if [ -d "$var" ]; then 
    folder=$(find $var/* -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l)
    file=$(find $var/* -maxdepth 0 -type f | wc -l)
    echo "Found: $folder folders "
    echo "       $file files $size bytes" 
  fi 
# error message 
else 
  echo "dir: Error \"$var\": No such file or directory"
fi
```

The problem is when the argument contains an asterisk (*), the `ls` within the script acts differently compare to the direct `ls` command given at the prompt. Instead of return the whole files list, the script only returns the first file. See the video below to see the comparation in action. I don't know why it behaves like that.

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you.

Video: [problem in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIGAf.gif)

---

**UPDATE**:

The problem has been solved. Thank you all for the answers. Now my script works as expected. See the video here: http://i.giphy.com/3o8dp1YLz4fIyCbOAU.gif

Comment: The first rule about `ls` is that you [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  You can do the summing with `du`.

Comment: It's said "Even better, most people don't really want a list of filenames. They want to do things to files instead." But I *do* want a list of filenames and the command to do it is `ls`. It's a `dir` command. So, how to do it correctly?

Comment: Man, Choroba already gave you the exact answer. Cong Ma also, with more words and explicitly told you what is your mistake. You simply don't want **think** about the answers. Your script has multiple issues and mainly because you don't want accept the basic facts. But ok:  want pass the asterisk to the script? - quote the arg, e.g. use the `dir.sh 'test*'` In such case the script will get the `test*` argument, **but this doesn't helps you and the script will not work anyway** - because this isn't how the `bash` works.

Comment: I believe you have the wrong mindset. Don't try to mimic on Linux what MSDOS or Windows is doing. Learn Linux with a fresh mind. Globbing and argument passing is *profoundly* different between Linux & MSDOS. So IMHO trying to reproduce MSDOS `dir` command is a wrong goal

Comment: The `if [ -a` test should be `if [ -f` or in modern bash `if [[ -f`. You can read on the differences betwen `[` and `[[` [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash). Your first test can be replaced by `var=${1:-.}` you can read on parameter expansion [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts) and [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: Serious question, why did you want to emulate the `dir` command? Perhaps just as a challenge exercise, or is there some missing functionality you needed? I see the video of your problem, the link to your solution is not working anymore, perhaps you could just add the code in your dir.sh to the update so we can see what you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The asterisk `*` is expanded by the shell when it parses the command line. In other words, your script doesn't get a parameter containing an asterisk, it gets a list of files as arguments. Your script only works with `$1`, the first argument. It should work with `"$@"` instead.

Comment: I know. I've tried replacing all `"$1"` with `"$@"`, it didn't work. :(

Comment: @BeeJay: Of course, `$1` and `$var` are normal variables, but `$@` is an array.

Comment: Then, it's not what I need. So, is it basically impossible to pass arbitrary string as argument to `ls` inside a script? Alright then.

Comment: @BeeJay yes, you **want** the `$@ list`, because the `bash` uses it. If want a shell which parses the command line differently, you must first write your own shell...

Comment: Yes, I think it's the only way. It's not as simple as I hope, but that's fine. Perhaps that's just the way Linux works. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is because when you retrieve `$1` you assume the shell does NOT expand `*`.

In fact, when `*` (or other glob) matches, it is expanded, and broken into segments by `$IFS`, and then passed as `$1`, `$2`, etc.

You're lucky if you simply retrieved the first file.  When your first file's path contains spaces, you'll get an error because you only get the first segment before the space.

Seriously, read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and especially [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).  Really.

---

And please don't do things like

```
CMD=whatever you get from user input; $CMD;
```

You are begging for trouble.  Don't execute arbitrary string from the user.

Comment: Ok, you right, I'm wrong. So, how to pass argument into `ls` command in a script correctly? Why does it seem so difficult?

Comment: @BeeJay it isn't difficult. Just (cite from choroba's answer): _The asterisk * is expanded by the shell when it parses the command line._ What do you still not understand?

Answer (score 3):

Both above answers already answered your question. So, i'm going a bit more verbose.

In your terminal is running the `bash` interpreter (probably). This is the program which parses your input line(s) and doing "things" based on your input.

When you enter some line the `bash` start doing the following workflow:

1. parsing and lexical analysis
2. expansion

   1. brace expansion
   2. tidle expansion
   3. variable expansion
   4. artithmetic and other substitutions
   5. command substitution
   6. word splitting
   7. filename generation (globbing)
3. removing quotes

Only after all above the `bash`

- will execute some external commands, like `ls` or `dir.sh`... etc.,
- or will do so some "internal" actions for the known keywords and `builtins` like `echo`, `for`, `if` etc...

As you can see, the second last is the **filename generation (globbing)**. So, in your case - if the `test*` matches some files, your `bash` **expands** the willcard characters (aka does the globbing).

So,

- when you enter `dir.sh test*`,
- **and** the `test*` matches some files
- the bash does the expansion **first**
- and after will execute the command `dir.sh` **with already expanded filenames**
- e.g. the script get executed (in your case) as: `dir.sh test.pas test.swift`

BTW, it acts exactly with the **same** way for your `ls` example:

- the `bash` expands the `ls test*` to `ls test.pas test.swift`
- then executes the `ls` with the above two arguments
- and the `ls` will print the result for the got **two** arguments.
- with other words, the `ls` don't even see the `test*` argument - if it is possible - the `bash` expands the wilcard characters. (`*` and `?`).

Now back to your script: add after the shebang the following line:

```
echo "the $0 got this arguments: $@"
```

and you will immediatelly see, the real argumemts how your script got executed.

also, in such cases is a good practice trying to execute the script in debug-mode, e.g.

```
bash -x dir.sh test*
```

and you will see, what the script does exactly.

Also, you can do the same for your current interpreter, e.g. just enter into the terminal

```
set -x
```

and try run the `dir.sh test*` = and you will see, how the `bash` will execute the `dir.sh` command. (to stop the debug mode, just enter `set +x`)

Comment: The above answers only show my mistakes. Fine, I did some mistakes, hence the question. The above answers only focus on the problems, not the solutions. I've read all the links they gave me. Yes, I understand bash will do its things on special characters. Then how to prevent it? Nope, I found no simple answers about how to pass asterisk into `ls` comnand inside a script. Even they suggest me to not use `ls`.

However, I think I found the solution. So, thank you all for the answers anyway.

Comment: Already [told you in above comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461543/how-to-pass-asterisk-into-ls-command-inside-bash-script/34469992?noredirect=1#comment56681139_34461543) how to prevent the expansion. Just quote the asterisk. for example try `ls 'test*'` the answer will be _ls: test*: No such file or directory_ - because the wildcard expansion isn't the `ls`'s job. It is a `bash`'s job - and it does it right.

Answer (score 1):

Everbody is giving you valuable advice which you should definitely should follow!

But here is the real answer to your question.

To pass unexpanded arguments to any executable you need to single quote them:

```
./your_script '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have is to use the eval command, in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="some command \"with_quetes_and_asterisk_in_it*\""
echo "$cmd"
eval $cmd
```

The eval command takes its arguments and evaluates them into the command as the shell does.
This solves my problem when I need to call a command with asterisk '*' in it from a script.